# Adding array of Uris into a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, arraylist, imageview, adapter

When setting an ArrayList of Uris in the gridView, only one item is displayed. Why ?

Adapter:

```
public class ImageGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;

public ImageGridAdapter(Context c) {

    this.mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    try {
        return PictureGroupActivity.ALofSelectedImgs.size();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return PictureGroupActivity.ALofSelectedImgs.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    }  else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    try {
        imageView.setImageURI(PictureGroupActivity.ALofSelectedImgs.get(position));
        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "Idee: " + PictureGroupActivity.ALofSelectedImgs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (NullPointerException e) {}

    return imageView;
}
```

Setting the adapter:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.picture_group_activity_layout);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.picture_group_gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageGridAdapter(this));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(PictureGroupActivity.this, "You clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

From where I take the Image (After choosing from the phones gallery):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        selectedImage = data.getData();

            ALofSelectedImgs = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            ALofSelectedImgs.add(selectedImage);


        Intent restart = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(restart);

    }
}
```

How do I make it add multiple Images into the ArrayList and make them stay there and not overwrite each other ?

Comment: Is that ArrayList <Uri> static? Looks like you're recreating it every time you select an image from the gallery

Comment: It is static, else I wouldn't be able to take it to the adapter, or would I ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems that I can see with your approach here.

The simplest solution (changing the least code). Would be to move `ALofSelectedImgs = new ArrayList();` from `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` and put it in `onCreate(Bundle)`.

This still won't persist the data between orientation changes or closing the app. You'll get a new empty ArrayList every time `onCreate(Bundle)` is called.

And I wouldn't recommend using static fields like that. For starters, you can't use ImageGridAdapter with any other Activity or Fragment. You need to pass the List to it, either in the constructor or a setter method. That way you can reuse it more easily.

```
private Context mContext;
private List<Uri> mUris;

public ImageGridAdapter(Context context, List<Uri> uris) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    mUris = uris;
}
```

For a better solution... there are many ways to do this. Here's what I'd do:

- Create a class extending SQLiteOpenHelper in order to save the selected Uris in an SQLite table. I learned a lot from this  [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html). I probably would not worry with a ContentProvider for something this simple. If you're interested I could pm you a template I use for keeping many tables' columns and other constants in a contract class.
- Create an adapter extending SimpleCursorAdapter to create Views from a Cursor containing a query from your SQLite table. This is explained in the above tutorial.
- In PhotoGroupActivity, perform a query of your table and initialize the adapter with the Cursor returned in `onCreate(Bundle)`.
- In `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` you need to insert the Uri into the SQLite table, then perform another query and give the adapter the new Cursor.

EDIT:
To answer your second question. This didn't occur to me at first, but you'll want to use thumbnails to display in your GridView. Use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap, int, int, boolean)` to create the thumbnail. Store the thumbnail in your app's private storage to avoid it going in your gallery, then add the Uri to the thumbnail to your ArrayList. You'll probably want to keep track of the Uri for the full-size image as well for when the user touches the thumbnail.

Try using HashMap with the thumbnail Uri as the key and the full-size Uri as the value.

```
// Create the HashMap like this:
HashMap<Uri, Uri> uriMap = new HashMap<>();

// You have the main Uri. Get the bitmap, create a thumbnail and store it.
// Add an entry to the HashMap like this:
uriMap.put(thumbnailUri, fullSizeUri);

// To get the list of thumbnail Uris for the adapter:
List<Uri> thumbnailList = new ArrayList<>(uriMap.keySet());

// When user presses an image in GridView, get the relevant full-size
// Uri like this:
fullSizeUri = uriMap.get(thumbnailUri);
```

EDIT AGAIN:
I looked again and realised I suggested a CursorAdapter and then gave info on how to get a HashMap of the data.

Instead, just add another column to the SQLite table and store both Uris there. When you obtain the Uri and thumbnail Uri, store them both in the table and query the table for the SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: Thank you! It did the trick. Ill check the tutorial link tomorrow when I'll have more time. ^^ But as for now, there's one more thing I'd like to ask. When adding images that were taken by the phones camera, the app gets really lagy (any manipulation with the gridView such as scrolling or even reloading when comming back to the activity makes the CPU usage jump up). When loading a bunch of these images the app crashes; but when loading small images, downloaded from the web, not even it doesn't crash, it wroks smoothly as well, any suggestions for solving this problem ?

Comment: Just remembered I have an example of this, unfinished but working. It was an assignment . Main difference is it uses camera for images, and stores String path for bitmaps rather than URIs.

Comment: Check DatabaseHelper.java and PhotoAdapter.java [link] (http://github.com/fletcherjohns/DailyDuckFace)

Comment: Already managed to do it, but thank you alot for the help ! :)